# Estimating Marketing Contribution from Opted-In Users

Tags: statistical-significance, sampling, marketing

I'm trying to estimate how much marketing contributes to the usage of our product, but because of consent requirements, I can only collect data on a subset of users - the ones who have consented to us collecting and analyzing their data for a marketing purpose.

**My question relates to how many users I will need to provide that consent to make any reliable inferences about marketing contribution,** where marketing contribution is defined as the percent of users who first used our product after clicking on a marketing URL.  I've been thinking of it like a sampling problem - how large a sample do I need to get a statistically significant measure of marketing contribution with a user base (population) of 30 million users, given a 99% confidence interval and a 1% margin of error?  (setting aside for now the fact that having user opt in could be introducing sampling bias.)

I just need a rough approximation to gut check whether it seems like an attainable number before we go through all the effort of obtaining said consent so I've tried plugging some numbers into some online tools but the numbers I'm getting back for sample size are so small, I don't trust the results. ~17k out of 30 million users?  I must be making an error somewhere in how I'm framing this.

Is sample size the wrong way to be thinking about this? How should I be thinking about the opt in rate I'll need for the data I collect to suffice for analytics purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there are $N = 30,000,000$ users. For each user let their response be "Yes" if the first time they used the product was after seeing a marketing email and "No" otherwise. Let $p$ be the proportion of users in the population who are "Yes". We want to construct a 99% confidence interval for $p$ which has bounds of plus or minus 1%.

A standard result in introductory textbooks on sampling theory (eg, Elementary Survey Sampling, Scheaffer, Mendenhall, Ott, Gerow) gives

$$
n = \frac{Npq}{(N-1)(B/Z_{\alpha/2})^2 + pq}
$$

where $B$ is the bound on the error of estimation, $Z_{\alpha/2}$ is the critical value from the standard normal distribution, $q=1-p$, and $p$ is the estimated proportion. If you don't have a previous estimate then using $p=0.5$ gives the most conservative bound. Plugging in your numbers and $p=0.5$ gives

$$
n = \frac{30000000\times0.5^2}{29999999(0.01/2.576)^2 + 0.5^2} = 16578
$$

That sounds like it matches what you found in online calculators. If we assume that you're taking a random sample from the population, it's correct. This is similar to how government statistics agencies are able to make conclusions about a population of 300 million people based on samples of only 10,000 - 100,000 people.

In my mind the bigger issue is the potential selection bias by only having self-selected users provide their data. I don't know how it would affect the results in this situation, but my intuition is that any errors from the selection effect would be much larger than errors from the confidence interval calculation. You'll need to inspect the rate of people who agree to share their data and compare that rate to the conclusions you find from the confidence interval.